# Word macro status bar message disappear

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a script that sends mails out at a random time.
Now I want it to indicate the current status in the status bar, e.g. "3 of 73 mails sent".

1. I managed to get it to output the current number, how do I output the total number?
2. The status bar doesn't display my information anymore, as soon as I click on Word, it disappears and doesn't show up. It then shows only the current word number.

```
' Merges one record at a time to email with a pre-defined delay between messages.
' Sourced from: https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/38282-email-merge-delay.html
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Dim i As Long
With ActiveDocument
  For i = 1 To .MailMerge.DataSource.RecordCount
  aktuell = i
    With .MailMerge
      .Destination = wdSendToEmail
      .MailSubject = "TECOSIM wünscht frohe Weihnachten!"
      .MailFormat = wdMailFormatHTML
      .MailAddressFieldName = "EMAIL"
      .SuppressBlankLines = True
            With .DataSource
        .FirstRecord = i
        .LastRecord = i
        .ActiveRecord = i
      End With
      .Execute Pause:=False
        End With
        Dim PauseDelay As Long
    PauseDelay = Int((480 - 300 + 1) * Rnd + 300) '
    Application.StatusBar = "Der Versand wird aktuell durchgeführt..." & aktuell & " gesendet."
    Call Pause(PauseDelay) ' Calls Pause with the random interval
  Next i
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Public Function Pause(Delay As Long)
Dim Start As Long
Start = Timer
If Start + Delay > 86399 Then
  Start = 0: Delay = (Start + Delay) Mod 86400
  Do While Timer > 1
    DoEvents ' Yield to other processes.
  Loop
End If
Do While Timer < Start + Delay
  DoEvents ' Yield to other processes.
Loop
End Function


I hope you can help me.
```

Comment: 1. Declare a new variable: `Dim TotalNumer as Long` then `TotalNumer = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.RecordCount `. In order to display it you must modify: `Application.StatusBar = "Der Versand wird aktuell durchgeführt..." & aktuell & " from " & TotalNumber & " gesendet." `                                                        2. Try adding `DoEvents` before the line `Application.StatusBar = "Der...."

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Dim i As Long, j As Long
With ActiveDocument
  j = .MailMerge.DataSource.RecordCount
  For i = 1 To j
    ...
    Application.StatusBar = "Senden läuft ... " & i & " von " & j & " gesendet."
```